# util-linux/lsblk :: how to use api/include

Tags: c++, centos7, fedora

I would like to use the lsblk identification functions in a c++ app, so i would like to link to it but i see no lsblk.h within packages of cento 7 or fedora. What is the proper way to find and use lsblk.h in centos/fedora distros?
L.E. actually the goal is to use/re-use some parts of lsblk and to make my life easier it would have been nice to include the `lsblk.h` and then use just the declarations that i need. so `to link` was really poorly worded intent.

Comment: Why do you expect to have a `lsblk.h` file? Where from? `lsblk identification functions` What functions are these exactly?

Comment: @KamilCuk: See `https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/tree/master/misc-utils` - it's not weird to expect it in Fedora if you have `lsblk` itself. The misunderstanding is probably a level deeper. `lsblk.h` contains declarations, but _where are the compiled bodies of those functions_? The question presupposes a `liblsblk.so`

Comment: It's not unreasonable.  Many linux command line utilities are a wrapper over a library.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `blkid.h`, not `lsblk.h`. You'll need `libblkid-devel` for that.

`lsblk` is a command-line utility, but for C++ you want a library instead. If you *do* want to use a command-line utility, you'd use `popen` from `stdio.h`.

Comment: well, i asked about `lsblk.h` because there is `https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/lsblk.h` but i did not find this file in any devel ... so, yes, i worded very poorly my goal: i want to reproduce a little bit of lsblk functions without doing everything so it's include would have been useful no matter what other linkage i have .. i think that in the end i will just use the system command

Comment: @AdrianSevcenco : `system` is incovenient, as it doesn't return output. You want `popen` instead.

Comment: i meant as a generic term/procedure not the actual `std::system` :)